# Java 8 Lambda: Can I generate a new ArrayList of objects from an IntStream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a Card class

```
public class Card {

   private int value, suit;

   public Card(int value, int suit) {
       this.value = value;
       this.suit = suit;
   }

   //gets, sets, toString
}
```

This is how I would normally fill the ArrayList of Card

```
for(int suit = 1; suit <= 4; ++suit)
    for(int value = 1; value <= 13; ++value)
        Cards.add(new Card(value, suit));
```

But I want to use a Lambda expression to initialize it

```
ArrayList<Card> Cards = IntStream.range(1, 4)
                           .map(value -> IntStream.range(1, 13)
                               .map(suit -> new Card(value, suit)));
```

Intellij is giving me an error under `.map(suit -> new Card(suit, value))`

It says "Incompatible return type Card in lambda expression"

Comment: I would personally keep using the old Java 7 style here, this situation does not suit *that well* for stream usage.

Comment: If this were a real application I would probably do that, but I'm just doing this to better learn Lambdas.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
List<Card> cards = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)
    .boxed()
    .flatMap(value -> 
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 13)
            .mapToObj(suit -> new Card(value, suit))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Points to note:

- you have to box the ints because `flatMap` on primitives doesn't have any 
    type-conversion overloads like `flatMapToObj` (doesn't exist);
- assign to `List` rather than `ArrayList` as the `Collectors` methods make no 
    guarantee as to the specific type they return (as it happens it currently is 
    `ArrayList`, but you can't rely on that);
- use `rangeClosed` for this kind of situation.

Comment: Added a answer based on the idea that IntStream::flatMapToObj(IntFunction<Stream<OBJ>>) is equivalent to IntStream::mapToObj(IntFunction<Stream<OBJ>>) then Stream::flatMap(Function<Stream<OBJ>, Stream<OBJ>>).

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get what you want (based on Maurice Naftalin's answer):

```
List<Card> cards = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)
  .mapToObj(value -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 13)
    .mapToObj(suit -> new Card(value, suit))
  )
  .flatMap(Function.identity())
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

Additional points to note:

- you have to map the int values to Stream streams, then flatMap said streams via Function.identity(), since flatMapToObj does not exists, yet said operation is translatable to a map to Stream, then an identity flatMap.

Comment: I like this better than my solution, even though @skiwi's comment above still stands—the imperative version is still better.